# how to get the Locale list in en_<COUNTRY> format

Tags: java

I want to return a list of all the countries in `<lang>_<Country>` format where `<lang>` should be english,
So I need a list like en_GB,en_US,en_JP etc. Looking at the Locale's api is returning `<lang>_<Country>` but it is not restricting it to language as en. 
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
    Locale[] availableLocales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
    for (Locale locale : availableLocales) {
        if ("en".equals(locale.getLanguage())) {
            System.out.println(locale);
        }
    }
```

you can filter the list to only include en as the language.

**note**: some Locales have a language but no country

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
        Locale[] allLocales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
        String desiredLanguage="en";
        List<Locale> desiredLocales = new ArrayList<Locale>();
        for(Locale locale:allLocales) {
            if(locale.getLanguage().equals(desiredLanguage)) {
                desiredLocales.add(locale);
                System.out.println("added: "+locale);
            }
        }
```

?